# Create Store Programmatically on frontend

Tags: magento2, store-view

I want to create stores/store_views programmatically from the frontend. Is it possible to do that?

I have not found any useful tutorial explaining to create stores/store views.

I am using Magento 2.4.1

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to create store programetically.

```
/** @var  \Magento\Store\Model\Store $store */
$store = $this->storeFactory->create();
$store->load('my_custom_store_code');
if(!$store->getId()){
    $group = $this->groupFactory->create();
    $group->load('My Custom Group Name', 'name');
    $store->setCode('my_custom_store_code');
    $store->setName('Mu Custom Store Code');
    $store->setWebsite($website);
    $store->setGroupId($group->getId());
    $store->setData('is_active','1');
    $this->storeResourceModel->save($store);
    
    // Trigger event to insert some data to the sales_sequence_meta table (fix bug place order in checkout)
    $this->eventManager->dispatch('store_add', ['store' => $store]);
}
```

where :

```
storeFactory = Magento\Store\Model\StoreFactory
groupFactory = Magento\Store\Model\GroupFactory
$website = Magento\Store\Model\Website
storeResourceModel = Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, I have added my own answer to the question. 
For anyone who is looking to achieve the same result.

Comment: There is a anot way to create it https://www.addeos.com/magento-2-create-new-stores-using-a-store-create-processor

Answer (score 1):

Here I am posting my answer. I hope this will help someone

```
    <?php
    
    namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller;
    
    use Magento\Store\Model\GroupFactory;
    use Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Group;
    use Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store;
    use Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website;
    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreFactory;
    use Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
    
    class myClass extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{
    
        protected $groupResourceModel;
        protected $storeResourceModel;
        protected $websiteFactory;
        protected $websiteResourceModel;
        protected $groupFactory;
        protected $eventManager;
        protected $storeFactory;
    
         public function __construct(
            Group $groupResourceModel,
            GroupFactory $groupFactory,
            ManagerInterface $eventManager,
            Store $storeResourceModel,
            StoreFactory $storeFactory,
            Website $websiteResourceModel,
            WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory
        ) {
            $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
            $this->groupFactory = $groupFactory;
            $this->groupResourceModel = $groupResourceModel;
            $this->storeFactory = $storeFactory;
            $this->storeResourceModel = $storeResourceModel;
            $this->websiteFactory = $websiteFactory;
            $this->websiteResourceModel = $websiteResourceModel;
        }
    
        public function execute(){
            $attribute =[
                    'website_code' => 'sitea',
                    'website_name' => 'Site A',
                    'group_name' => 'Site A Online Store',
                    'store_code' => 'site_a_online_store_view',
                    'store_name' => 'Site A Store View',
                    'is_active' => '1'
            ];
    
            $store = $this->storeFactory->create();
            $store->load($attribute['store_code']);
                
            if(!$store->getId()){
                /** @var \Magento\Store\Model\Website $website */
                $website = $this->websiteFactory->create();
                $website->load($attribute['website_code']);
                $website = $this->setWebID($website, $attribute);
    
                /** @var \Magento\Store\Model\Group $group */
                $group = $this->groupFactory->create();
                $group->setWebsiteId($website->getWebsiteId());
                $group->setName($attribute['group_name']);
                $this->groupResourceModel->save($group);
    
    
                $group = $this->groupFactory->create();
                $group->load($attribute['group_name'], 'name');
                $store->setCode($attribute['store_code']);
                $store->setName($attribute['store_name']);
                $store->setWebsite($website);
                $store->setGroupId($group->getId());
                $store->setData('is_active', $attribute['is_active']);
                $this->storeResourceModel->save($store);
                $this->eventManager->dispatch('store_add', ['store' => $store]);
                $store = $this->storeFactory->create();
return true;
            }
    
            public function setWebID($website, $attribute){
                if(!$website->getId()){
                    $website->setCode($attribute['website_code']);
                    $website->setName($attribute['website_name']);
                    $this->websiteResourceModel->save($website);
                }
                return $website;
            }
        }
    }
```

This will create your website, store, store view

Comment: There is a anot way to create it https://www.addeos.com/magento-2-create-new-stores-using-a-store-create-processor

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution. Helped me a lot.